# Code for finding combination containing 0's and 1's in python

Tags: python

I'm doing a program to find the no .of possible arrangements from a binary list...
I wrote code but some mistake is there...getting wrong output...

```
  import math
x=list(map(int, input().split()))
zero=0
one=0
for i in x:
    if x[i]==0:
        zero=zero+1
    else :
        one=one+1
print(math.factorial(len(x))//(math.factorial(zero)*math.factorial(one)) )
```

when I give
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
as input I'm getting 1 as answer

Comment: It should be `if i == 0:`...Because `i` is a value in the list and `x[i]` is either `x[0]` or `x[1]` which are both `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a couple minor adjustments to your snippet and fixed your code

Here is the updated version, output is 210

```
import math

x=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
zero=0
one=0
for i in x:
    if i==0:
        zero=zero+1
    else:
        one=one+1

print(math.factorial(len(x))//(math.factorial(zero)*math.factorial(one)))
```